# VS 2012 project load error, incompatible .Net version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-framework-version

I'm getting an error when I try to load a project in VS 2012. This project was created on the same machine and it was working fine but now it has started to complain about project target framework.

[image: VS2012 error while loading project]

From the error message I don't understand the difference between .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 and change target to .Net Framework 4.5
When I choose to download and install .NETFramework,Version=v4.5, the installer says this version is already part of OS and need not be installed separately.
I'm working on VS 2012 on Windows 8 64 bit OS.

Any pointers will be helpful, Thanks

Comment: That sounds messed-up. Have you looked at the .csproj file in a text editor to see if anything weird has happened? Also try the usual trick of deleting the bin and obj folders and any .suo files (with VS closed) and then try rebuilding. Also, if you create a new project, does that work ok?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not happening with ONLY this project. I\m getting error while loading all the existing projects. Only difference before things worked and now is that I installed WP8 SDK.